# How to read a csv-file from an url in R?

Tags: r, url, readr

I'm rather new to R and I could use your assistance.

I am currently trying to import a csv file from an URL. I have found many examples. Unfortunately, none of them work for my problem.

Specifically, I wanted to import the file from this url: https://www.bfs.admin.ch/bfsstatic/dam/assets/15324797/master

I tried these few lines of code:

```
temp <- tempfile()

download.file("https://www.bfs.admin.ch/bfsstatic/dam/assets/15324797/master",temp, mode =  "w")

data<- read_csv2("je-b-03.03.02.05.csv")
```

and also this:

```
data <- read_csv2(url("https://www.bfs.admin.ch/bfsstatic/dam/assets/15324797/master"))
```

But that didn't work either. On the other hand, when I paste the url into my browser, the file is downloaded automatically.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: In your first example, you should do `read.csv2(temp)`, since that's the destination of your download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df <- read.csv2(file = url("https://www.bfs.admin.ch/bfsstatic/dam/assets/15324797/master"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps to begin with:

```
data <- read.csv(url("https://www.bfs.admin.ch/bfsstatic/dam/assets/15324797/master"))
```

Check `?read.csv`for details.

Answer (score 0):

I've found [vroom](https://www.jimhester.com/tags/vroom/) to be the best option for this type of task:

```
install.packages("vroom")
library(vroom)
data <- vroom("https://www.bfs.admin.ch/bfsstatic/dam/assets/15324797/master")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
loc.url <- "https://www.bfs.admin.ch/bfsstatic/dam/assets/15324797/master"

data <- read.csv2(loc.url)
```

Comment: I am not saying your answer is wrong, but please provide a bit more context to why it is correct.

Comment: @chrisAR Please provide some context in your answer

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html

Comment: Look on that line:"file can also be a complete URL. (For the supported URL schemes, see the ‘URLs’ section of the help for url."